# What does 'as' method do in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In the example from the tutorial, it shows up.

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admin',                        
    'as' => 'admin.'                            
], function () {}
```

Can someone tells me what 'as' does? Also, is the dot next to the 'admin' neccessary?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say, for example, that you have this route:

```
Route::get('admin', [
    'as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@index'
]);
```

By using *as* you assign custom name to your route. So now, Laravel will allow you to reference said route by using:

```
$route = route('admin');
```

So you don't have to build the URL manually over and over again in your code. You don't really need `.` notation if you only want to call your route `admin`. If you want a more detailed name of your route, lets say for ex. `admin product route`, then you use the `.` notation, like this:

```
Route::get('admin/product', [
    'as' => 'admin.product', 'uses' => 'AdminController@showProduct'
]);
```

So now, you will be able to call this route by the assigned name:

```
$route = route('admin.product');
```

**Update:**

The previous answer I provided is valid for a single routes. For the route groups, the procedure is very similar. In the route groups you need the `.` notation when you add a custom name, since you will be referencing another route after that `.` notation. This will allow you to set a common route name prefix for all routes within the group. So by your example, lets say you have a dashboard route inside your admin route group:

```
Route::group(['as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', function () {
        //Some logic
    }]);
});
```

Now, you will be able to call the dashboard route like this:

```
$route =  route(admin.dashboard);
```

You can read more about this in Laravel official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes).

Comment: Just to add, this is particularly useful because if you want to change the URL of the route you just have to update the routes file and not the code (as it will be using named routes).

Comment: `admin.product` is name of route group, not route so you can't call `route('admin.product');`

Comment: You're completely right. I just realized this is a route group. Will update my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you may specify an as keyword in the route group attribute array, allowing you to set a **common route name prefix** for all routes within the group.

> For Example

```
Route::group(['as' => 'admin::'], function () {

    // Route named "admin::"
});
```

> UseRoute Name *like* **{{route(admin::)}}** or **route('admin::')**

Answer (score 0):

you can use an 'as' as a named route. if you do not prefix your route name in group route than you may add custom route name like this.

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'], 'roles' => ['2']], function () {

```
 Route::post('/changeProfile', ['uses' => 'UserController@changeProfile',
    'as' => 'changeProfile']);
```

});